# Changing frame of UIView through IBOutlet from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var outletView: UIView! //Referencing Outlet connected
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //not working
    outletView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)

    //working
    var view = UIView();
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 100);
    self.view.addSubview(view);
}
```

How can I edit frame of @IBoutlet view as normal UIView instance?

---

I solved it to remove `Use Size Classes` on StoryBoard inspector.

Comment: try self .outletView.frame and weak into strong

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Same. Not working.
But ''outletView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor();'' is working well.

Comment: can u say plz whats ur previous outletView.frame size

Comment: In Storyboard,
Intrinsic Size in constraints option is Defaults. 
and Size Inspector set x:0, y:0, width:300, height:67.

Comment: I think this problem is caused by Storyboard.

Comment: if u r using the auto layout, remove the old constraint and add the new constraints ,in another choice use autoresizing

Comment: I solved it to remove 'Use Size Classes'.
@Anbu.Karthik Thanks.

Comment: have a happy day bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `frame` in `ViewDidload` method , it first assigns the frame that you set in`ViewDidload` and then the `Storyboard` `Constraints` are applied so your `constraints` are over-ridden.

In order to change the `constraints` apply the `constraints` in `ViewDidAppear` method and it will be reflected

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) 
{

        outletView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 400)

}
```

Comment: problem is not in the frame that occur in the auto layout, can u suggest how to add the new constraints progrmatically

Comment: what edits have you made in the answer? i was unable to figure it out